# MongoDB cursor causes my function to skip step

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my check permission function, and it work fine, but i can't return result because function skip one step and first return "access" variable, then execute cursor function to check permission. I do not idea what i do wrong. Console logs approve that:

**Console result:**
*1
5 return here
2
3
3
3
4*

```
function permissionChecker(guildID, reqUserID, checkPexArray) {
    console.log("1")
    let access = false

    let pexUserCheckCursor = db.db("MainDB").collection("Permissions").find({GuildID: guildID}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        console.log("2")
        let serverDB = result[0]
        let serverPexGroups = serverDB.PexGroups
        let serverPexGroupsNames = Object.keys(serverPexGroups)

        //Object of user's pexes.
        let serverPexUsers = serverDB.PexUsers
        //Looking for at least one of required pexes.
        for (let reqPex of checkPexArray) {
            for (let pexName in serverPexUsers) {
                console.log("3")

                //If reqPex has in DB
                if (reqPex == pexName) {
                    for (let userID of serverPexUsers[pexName]) {
                        //If req user has req pex.
                        if (userID == reqUserID) {
                            console.log("4")
                            access = true
                            return

                        } else {
                            access = false
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    console.log("5 return here")
}
```

Comment: I recommend you read about promises and how they work, for example here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-promises-explained/#:~:text=What%20is%20a%20promise%20in,operation%2C%20and%20its%20resulting%20value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console output is correct, cause the db read is asynchronous.

Consider changing `permissionChecker` to an `async function` and then `await` the db callback result.
Or change the `permissionChecker` function to return a `new Promise` and then `resolve(access)` after the loops.